# How to generate 5 percent unique numbers between 1 and 10 Million in oracle table?

Tags: java, data-generation

I have a task to generate unique numbers(in terms of percentage) in a given range. For example: I need to generate 10 million random numbers in an oracle table out of which 5% values are unique.

Comment: Show us what you've written so far.

Comment: I suggest reading the following link, it will be much clearer to you then: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my design:

1. 5% from 10 million is half a million. so you can reserve the range of 1-500,000 for unique numbers.
2. when you generate the sequence of random numbers, you generate random number in the range 500,001 - 10,000,000 and every 20th call, take the next number from the reserved pool

Comment: Don't think you should answer to these kind of questions. OP has clearly put no effort in trying to come up with a solution and it will probably be removed by moderators or the flagging system soon anyway.

Comment: if the problem was trivial, or could be answered using search engine, then I wouldn't answer. but IMO this question is neither. it is possible that OP doesn't know how to design a solution. I offered a high level design, not a working code sample.